# Nightwatch elementCount before an amount of time

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js

Trying to test with `Nightwatch.js`, that a dropdown has a given number of items before a certain amount of time.

On way is to :

```
browser
  .pause(300)
  .assert.elementCount('#project_switch .dropdown-item', 3)
```

But this is ugly, forcing to spread so many `.pause(value)` in the test code thus making the e2e test far longer than what is necessary!

I think I should switch from `browser.assert` to `browser.expect` which offers the `before(ms)` but what is the way to count the elements with `browser.expect` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since, in my case, this dropdown has by default 1 element, but will have more after an AJAX call, the following does the thing smoothly and without unnecessary pause :

```
browser
  .waitForElementPresent('#project_switch .dropdown-item:nth-of-type(2)', 300)
  .assert.elementCount('#project_switch .dropdown-item', 3)
```